# Summation of series to n terms in trigonometry of complex numbers

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, binomial-theorem, geometric-progressions

The question says that: Sum the series 
[image: summation of series question 8]

I have solved the answer as follows:[image: answer to question 8]

As the above picture, I don’t know what should I do after the step. 
The question asks to solve the problem using geometric progression or binomial theorem for complex quantities. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You properly arrived to
$$C+iS=1+\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k (k+1) e^{i a k}$$ Multiply both side by $e^{ia}$ to get
$$(C+iS)e^{ia}=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k (k+1) e^{i a (k+1)}$$ Integrate the rhs and let $x=e^{ia}$ to face something you know.

When done, differentiate the result.